# How to replace ¦ (broken bar) from a string?

Tags: java, string

I am getting a JSON response like this:

> Lorem ipsum ¦dolor sit amet

What I want to do is to replace all [broken bars](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a6/index.htm) (¦).

I have tried `.replaceAll("\u00A6", "");`, but it won't work.

Comment: "it won't work" doesn't give us enough information about *exactly* what you've tried, or what happened. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just a thought: maybe use `¦` as the first parameter?

Comment: Also, note that you can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: Well, I am very new to this.
I have String like “flksadjf¦dsakfjd”, and I want to get rid of the broken bar.
So I tried str.replaceAll("\u00A6", "");, and display the string in a Label (smartGWT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're not assigning the result, and that's why you're not getting the desired output. Note that `replace` and `replaceAll` **returns** a new string, they doesn't modify the string in-place.

It should actually work. But if you have problems, keep in mind that you can use it directly:

```
String str = "sdfsdf¦sdfsdf"
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("¦", ""));
// Output: sdfsdfsdfsdf
```

Also there's no need for `replaceAll`, you can use `replace` instead (that doesn't accept a regex).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I expected the `replace()` method to modify the string.
What a silly mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use unicode "\u00A6" use the char broken bars char (¦) to replace. Its Working.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Lorem ipsum ¦dolor sit amet";
        String Str1 = str.replace("¦", "&");
        System.out.println(Str1);
    }
Output -  Lorem ipsum &dolor sit amet
```

You can replace it with empty string "". I use & for demonstration.